# Поменять Image.Source в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю приложение с WPF. В форме есть кнопка для запуска exe файла, который меняет фотографию photo.jpg и выводит это фото в image. На данный момент для того, чтобы показывалась последняя фотография, необходимо перезапускать приложение целиком. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы после каждого нажатия показывалась последняя версия photo.jpg. Вот часть кода, которая это делает.

```cs
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = path + @"\emotion_recognition_py\test.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

string command = "move " + path + @"\photo.jpg " + path.Substring(0, path.Length - 10);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C " + command);
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("photo.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, достаточно было отключить кэширование изображений.

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.UriSource = new Uri("photo.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi.EndInit();

image.Source = bi;
```